# Is it possible to debug QML from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, debugging, qml

I have a QT project that loads a QML project. I've have no problem debugging the QML part of the program when I run it from QT Creator. I've added

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DQT_QML_DEBUG ")`

to my CMakeLists.txt and checked the "Enable QML" under "Debugger Settings" in "Project->Run"

But I would like to debug from Visual Studio, since that is the environment we usually work in.

Is it possible to manually do what QT Creator does when you check the "Enable QML" box, to activate debugging from Visual Studio? Attach to some process or similar?

I've tried to figure out what the "Enable QML" box actually does. But I've not been able to find any good explanation about this.

We use CMake to build, MSVC as compiler and CDB as debugger. The projects are in QT5.5 and QT Quick 2. Visual Studio is version 2015 Professional and QT Creator is version 4.1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Qt Visual Studio tools 2.3](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/10/08/qml-debugging-visual-studio/#comments), released in Oct 2018, the QML debugger is included and usable from Visual Studio :)